# why is kdb/q showing a big difference between used and heap space after GC

Tags: garbage-collection, kdb

As per this page, for versions 2.6 and 2.7 (http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/memory-management)

> 2.6 Unreferenced memory blocks over 32MB/64MB are returned immediately
>
> 2.7 Unreferenced memory blocks returned when memory full or .Q.gc[] called

But in both versions, there is a significant difference between used and heap space shown by .Q.w[]. This difference only grows as I run the function again. In 2.6, a difference could occur due to fragmentation (allocating many small objects) but I am not confident it accounts for this big of a difference. In 2.7, even after running .Q.gc[], it shows a significant difference. I would like to understand fundamentally the reason for this difference in the two versions as highlighted below.

**This is behavior I am seeing in 2.6 and 2.7:**

```
 2.6: 
    used| 11442889952
    heap| 28588376064

 2.7  (after running .Q.gc[])
    used| 11398025856
    heap| 16508780544
```

Comment: When you edit a question which are just not correcting simple mistakes but changing some important matter/idea , do not change the original question. Please add the edit tag at the end of question and append the new text there.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic Garbage collection doesn't clear small objects (<32MB) . In that case  manual GC call is required. If your process has lot of unreferenced small objects then that will add up in heap size and not to used size.

Second, since KDB allocates memory in power of 2, that makes the difference between used and heap memory. For ex.  if a vector requires 64000 bytes, it will be assigned a memory block of size 2^16 = 65536 bytes. And boundary cases makes this difference huge, for ex. if vector requires 33000 bytes (just over  2^15) it will be allocated 65536 bytes (2^16).

Following site has good explanation of GC behavior:
http://www.aquaq.co.uk/q/garbage-collection-kdb/

Comment: running .Q.gc[] in 2.7 still leaves a significant difference between used and heap, not as much as 2.6 but still notable. I am trying to understand where this difference is coming from. Secondly, how do I fix these issues in 2.6

Comment: To go into the depth, you need to do manual debugging of your program. Create some profiling function and use them for memory footprint tracing. One possible reason could be the memory allocation technique that I explained in the answer also because you have good amount of used memory. Also please try to upgrade to new KDB version.

Comment: Agreed. But fundamentally, why would there ever be a difference between used and heap after running .Q.gc[]. There is something that I am missing here. I would like to understand before a more in-depth analysis.